# Получение Token для push-сообщения через API HTTP v1

Tags: firebase, firebase-android, fcm

Через устаревший протокол HTTP-сервера (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) все работает.

Но вот через новый API я загруз на авторизации.
1. Как получить токен в скрипте php?

```
<?php
    $registrationIds = 'myAppID';

    $data = array(
        "key" => "value"
    );

    $notification = array(
        "title" => "Title" , 
        "body" => "Notification text" 
    );

    $message = array(
        "data" => $data,
        "notification" => $notification,
        "topic" => "news"
    );

    $body_msg = array(
        "validate_only" => false, 
        "message" => $message
    );

    $fields =  json_encode( $body_msg );

    $token = ''; //вот тут вопрос

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL,
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-12345/messages:send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    echo $result;
?>
```

2. Как сделать отправку сообщений из Android приложения?

Ткните меня носом на примеры, инструкции. В общем направьте в правильном направлении.